# Что символизирует => в приведенных примерах?

Tags: c#

```cs
public static void OutputResult(int? result, int expectedResult)  => Console.WriteLine($"Result:{result,4} Expected:{expectedResult,4}");`
```

и

```cs
public static int? Multiply(string arguments) => 0;
```

Comment: Можно вам вопрос: я дал ответ на ваш вопрос, но почему вы его не приняли? Возможно в нём какие-то проблемы с качеством, или что?

Comment: Первый раз принимал ответ. Уже принял

Comment: А жаль что закрыли, ответ там я бы дополнил.

Comment: Воу, @Grundy это методы, а не свойства. Если это и дубликат, то какого-нибудь другого вопроса, а не того, что по ссылке.

Comment: @aepot, суть та же, синтаксический сахар над объявлением функции

Comment: @Grundy верно, но по факту это не дубликат. Это может только запутать автора, и он перепутает методы и свойства. Для автора ссылка: [Члены, воплощающие выражения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members). Все-таки надо искать ответ в сети, прежде чем задавать вопрос здесь.

Comment: @aepot, дубликат, в ответе указано не только про свойства, но и про методы и свойства только для чтения.